# php/iis file_get_contents permission denied for uploaded file

Tags: php, iis, file-get-contents, permission-denied

After successfully uploading a file to *.../upload/tm/* I get an 500 error: permission denied when I want to read the contents of this file using `file_get_contents`.

```php
$target = 'upload/' . $data['folder'] . '/' . $filename;
if (move_uploaded_file($file[$data['name']]['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    // $success = true;
    chmod($target, 0755);
}
```

According to my research, when moving the temp-file to *.../upload/tm/*, the permissions are not inherited and stay the same as in *c:\windows\temp*.
So, I checked the permissions of both *c:\windows\temp* and *.../upload/tm/*. All of the indicated users have the same rw-permissions: IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, 'localmachine'$, 'localmachine'$/users, ...

I can solve this issue by manually re-apply the permissions of IUSR from the group or usernames in the Properties/Security tap of the parent folder *.../upload/tm/* from which the permissions are inherited. But I need an better solution because I don't want to repeat this each time a file is uploaded.

All help is much appreciated.

**Update**

Somehow, when moving the file from outside the webfoldertree, the permissions are messed up. When I change the temporary upload folder to a branch of the same tree, the permissions are as suspected; the file is accessable and I can get its contents.

This solves the outcome of my problem, but the question is still for what reason I cannot get the contents with `file_get_contents()`, although the permissions look the same. I would rather keep the tempfolder on its original place.

Comment: Do you mean that `c:\windows\temp` and `. . . /upload/tm/` have the same authority for all users? If so, the temp files are moved to `.../upload/tm/` with the same permissions. What permissions are not being inherited?

Comment: When I check the permissions of both files and folders, the permissions look exacly the same.  But file_get_contents has no access. When I manually re-apply the permissions the upload-folder, they look the same, but  this time, the file is accessable.

Comment: Maybe you can try a more permissive permission setting, such as 0777, to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @YurongDai no luck, nothing is changed with the permisions.

Comment: Someone other ideas?

Comment: I moved the temp folder (c:\window\temp) to the root 'www/temp_upload/'. (created new folder and changed the settings in php.ini) 
Now, it works as expected. 
Preferably, I would hold those seperated from each other. Would it bother?

Comment: From a security standpoint, separating temp folders from web files helps reduce the attack surface and protects your server from potential threats, and it adds an extra layer of security to your file upload functionality. But these are unknown, as you said now it works as expected.